# Get First and Last Entry in Table by User within SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that captures users weight and body fat percentage. I'm looking for a sql query that will get all the users along with their first and last entries (so I may workout total weight lost etc.)

The table structure is as follows:

```
UserName NVARCHAR(128)
DateTimeStamp DateTime
BodyWeight DECIMAL(18,2)
BodyFatPercentage DECIMAL(18,2)
```

I'd like the data returned as follows:

```
Username|First Date|Weight|Body Fat Percentage|Last Date|Weight|Body Fat Percentage|
John|21 January 2015|80|25|14 February 2015|76|22|
Mary|15 January 2015|55|19|12 February 2015|53|18|
Danny|10 January 2015|75|23|10 February 2015|70|19|
Saul|05 January 2015|77|28|13 February 2015|76|27|
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't very clear. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign both ascending and descending row numbers per user.  The first entry for that user has ascending `row_number` 1, the last entry has descending `row_number` 1.  For example:

```
select  UserName
,       max(case when rn1 = 1 then DateTimeStamp end) as FirstDate
,       max(case when rn1 = 1 then BodyWeight end) as BW
,       max(case when rn1 = 1 then BodyFatPercentage end) as BFP
,       max(case when rn2 = 1 then DateTimeStamp end) as LastDate
,       max(case when rn2 = 1 then BodyWeight end) as BW
,       max(case when rn2 = 1 then BodyFatPercentage end) as BFP
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by UserName
                    order by DateTimeStamp) rn1
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by UserName
                    order by DateTimeStamp desc) rn2
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        UserName
```

Comment: You missed desc in one function

Comment: I just tried this with a temp table, and it's not working the way he wanted it?

Comment: @VedranKopanja: What is not working? Can you put your example on sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @VedranKopanja: You're right, whoops, I wrote `partition by User` instead of `partition by UserName`.  And `user` is a T-SQL reserved word that typically returns `dbo`.  Fixed in answer.

Comment: SQL Server 2012+ support `FIRST_VALUE`/`LAST_VALUE`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming MSSQL 2005 or newer, you can make use of the `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT
    users.Username,
    first.DateTimeStamp AS FirstDate,
    first.BodyWeight AS FirstWeight,
    first.BodyFatPercentage AS FirstPercentage,
    last.DateTimeStamp AS LastDate,
    last.BodyWeight AS LastWeight,
    last.BodyFatPercentage AS LastPercentage
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Username
    FROM User
) AS users
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM User
    WHERE User.Username = users.Username
    ORDER BY DateTimeStamp ASC
) AS first
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM User
    WHERE User.Username = users.Username
    ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC
) AS last
```

Well it turned a little bit ugly because I had to select a list of distinct usernames in a subquery from the `User` table, in a normalized database you probably already have the users in a separate table.

The `APPLY` operator gives us a handy way to perform a table-valued lookup for each user, i.e. we can get the first and last row for each user in a clean and structured way.

Comment: Might not be the fastest but certainly a correct way to write it, +1 :)

Comment: Assuming there is a list of distinct users, this is probably faster than the aggregation method.